# Swift Generic Type Variable should comply to a Protocol (type class)

Tags: generics, swift, protocols, type-constraints, type-variables

I am trying to write a helper function in swift, that allows to sort more conveniently. Here is what I have and what works:

```
someArray.sorted({ someGetter($0) < someGetter($1) })
```

Instead I would like to write

```
someArray.sorted(comparing(someGetter))
```

I was trying to define the comparing function like this

```
func comparing<A,B : Equatable>(f: A -> B) -> ((A,A) -> Bool) {
    return { f($0) < f($1) }
}
```

The problem is, that the type checker does not know, that 'B' needs to comply to the 'Equatable' protocol. I don't know how to achieve that. The compiler complains with '\'B\' is not convertible to \'UInt8\'', because it assumes two Ints to be compared by the '<' function. If I overwrite '<' for example with:

```
@infix func <(lhs: SomeType, rhs: SomeType) -> Bool {
    return lhs.i < rhs.i
}
```

then the compiler assumes SomeType instead of UInt8.

This is my second day playing around with Swift. I hope my question is not too stupid. I will probably have a bunch of other mistakes as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you need B to be `Equatable` - since you're comparing the values, you only need them to be `Comparable`:

```
func comparing<A, B: Comparable >(f: A -> B) -> (A,A) -> Bool {
    return { f($0) < f($1) }
}
```

If you **do** need B to conform to both `Equatable` and `Comparable`, you can use a where clause to add additional constraints:

```
func comparing<A, B: Comparable where B: Equatable>(f: A -> B) -> (A, A) -> Bool {
    return { f($0) < f($1) }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes,that was indeed the wrong protocol. Do you happen to know, why Comparable only defined <=, >=, and > and not <? I know it from another language, that one operator can be expressed by others. Do you know if Swift also supports some default implementation for methods in a protocol? There also could have been a generic definition of < that required the Comparable protocol, but I did only find one. Also for my class SomeType now implements Comparable but I did not need to provide further implementations. The '<'-implementation seems to be enough. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: If you've defined enough of the operators, the compiler can figure out the other ones. I'm guessing `SomeType` implements `Equatable`, too, right? If the compiler knows about `<` and `==`, it can put together `<=`, `>=`, and `>` by itself.